# NEW counter missed in statistics conntrack -S

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, linux-networking, nf-conntrack

From this question [Statistics /proc/net/stat/nf_conntrack is missing on Linux server](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080112/statistics-proc-net-stat-nf-conntrack-is-missing-on-linux-server/1080121?noredirect=1#comment1410113_1080121) I recognized that `/proc/net/stat/nf_conntrack` has an alternative `conntrack -S`.
In /proc/net/stat/nf_conntrack there is `NEW` counter, based on which the one can calculate CPS (connections per second) metric. But in `conntrack -S` I see no such a counter.

How can I obtain the `NEW` conntrack counter without `/proc/net/stat/nf_conntrack`? Is there a way to obtain it from `conntrack -S`?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel part displaying such statistics in the `/proc` filesystem method is [there](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_standalone.c?h=v5.4#n428):

> ```
>   if (v == SEQ_START_TOKEN) {
>       seq_puts(seq, "entries  searched found new invalid ignore delete delete_list insert insert_failed drop early_drop icmp_error  expect_new expect_create expect_delete search_restart\n");
>       return 0;
>   }
>
>   seq_printf(seq, "%08x  %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x "
>           "%08x %08x %08x %08x %08x  %08x %08x %08x %08x\n",
>          nr_conntracks,
>          0,
>          st->found,
>          0,
>          st->invalid,
>          st->ignore,
>          0,
>          0,
>          st->insert,
>          st->insert_failed,
>          st->drop,
>          st->early_drop,
>          st->error,
>
>          st->expect_new,
>          st->expect_create,
>          st->expect_delete,
>          st->search_restart
>       );
> ```

as can be seen, fields `searched` ([replaced by an other field](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_standalone.c?id=1702ad79d31ef236adcd9999fae7617e8eda515d) in later kernels), `new`, `delete`, `delete_list` always display 0: nothing feeds these fields.

As I suspected in my previous answer ("or might have been obsoleted") there is no statistic about this with the older method or the newer method.

Here is the [commit from 2016 that removed them](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.4&id=8e8118f893138d4cc3d4dbf4163d7497fca54a9d) (probably for kernel 4.9):

> netfilter: conntrack: remove packet hotpath stats
>
> These counters sit in hot path and do show up in perf, this is especially
> true for 'found' and 'searched' which get incremented for every packet
> processed.
>
> Information like
>
> searched=212030105
> new=623431
> found=333613
> delete=623327
>
> does not seem too helpful nowadays:
>
> - on busy systems found and searched will overflow every few hours
>   (these are 32bit integers), other more busy ones every few days.
> - for debugging there are better methods, such as iptables' trace target,
>   the conntrack log sysctls.  Nowadays we also have perf tool.
>
> This removes packet path stat counters except those that
> are expected to be 0 (or close to 0) on a normal system, e.g.
> 'insert_failed' (race happened) or 'invalid' (proto tracker rejects).
>
> The insert stat is retained for the ctnetlink case.
> The found stat is retained for the tuple-is-taken check when NAT has to
> determine if it needs to pick a different source address.
>
> Signed-off-by: Florian Westphal fw@strlen.de
> Signed-off-by: Pablo Neira Ayuso pablo@netfilter.org

### Alternative

You can use the [conntrackd](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/about.html) tool (packaged on Ubuntu [there](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/conntrackd)) that can be configured to log events to provide only logs and statistics (instead of its main use for transparent failover between multiple firewalls in a high availability cluster). Ubuntu might be providing a configuration for statistics by default (or in documentation). Here's an example on a system where the `conntrackd` service is running:

```
# conntrackd -s ct; sleep 5; conntrackd -s ct
[Fri Oct 15 08:34:08 2021] (pid=3443753) [warning] deprecated unix backlog configuration, ignoring.
cache stats:
current active connections:           65
connections created:              121807    failed:            0
connections updated:              116158    failed:            0
connections destroyed:            121742    failed:            0

traffic processed:
                   0 Bytes                         0 Pckts

[Fri Oct 15 08:34:13 2021] (pid=3443756) [warning] deprecated unix backlog configuration, ignoring.
cache stats:
current active connections:           68
connections created:              121811    failed:            0
connections updated:              116163    failed:            0
connections destroyed:            121743    failed:            0

traffic processed:
                   0 Bytes                         0 Pckts
```

The tool tells `connections created:` went from 121807 to 121811. I believe that's the equivalent of the `new` field removed from kernel.

Note: `traffic processed:` is certainly for firewall-to-firewall communication between two *conntrackd* daemons (so will always be 0 here).